# Как обновлять tableView в MVP

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, шаблоны-проектирования, mvp

Практикуюсь в написании проекта с использованием MVP. Есть задача - обновить таблицу после того, как новый элемент был добавлен в модель.

Метод внутри DataStorageObserver, который обновляет модель:

```
func addContact(contact: Contact) {
  DataStorage.sharedInstance.contactList.append(contact)
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(Constants.Identifiers.sharedInstance.contactListUpdateIdentifier, object: nil)
}
```

View реализует методы протокола

```
protocol ContactListViewProtocol: class {
  func updateData()
}
```

Сам метод обновления, который внутри View (роль которой играет UITableViewController)

```
func updateData() {
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Внутри пресентера есть метод:

```
required init(view: ContactListViewProtocol) {
  self.view = view
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ContactListViewProtocol.updateData), name: Constants.Identifiers.sharedInstance.contactListUpdateIdentifier, object: nil)
}
```

Xcode подсказывает о том, что последний required init содержит ошибку

> Argument of '#selector' refers to a method that is not exposed to
>   Objective-C

Если принять подсказку от Xcode, то он предлагает подставить к методу в **ContactListPresenterProtocol** метку @objc, который (метод) никак не относится к логике обновления (полагаю, что косяк ide). Как лучше следует реализовать обновление? Где следует проставить @objc? Стоит ли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка у вас в том, что вы вызываете updateData на self, а метод у вас в классе view

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self.view,selector: #selector(ContactListViewProtocol.updateData), name: Constants.Identifiers.sharedInstance.contactListUpdateIdentifier, object: nil)
```

Comment: Спасибо, то есть я могу вешать наблюдателей на любые вьюхи из их пересентеров, а я вешал наблюдателя на презентор, который дергал метод у вьюхи (за которую принимаю "uiviewcontroller"). Но есть один нюанс, как же мне тогда реализовать mvp, в котором модель сообщает пресентеру, что надо обновляться, и презентер дернет метод вьюхи, если я вешаю селектор на вьюху и вбрасываю нотификацию из модели (получается что я моделью обновляю вьюху)?

Answer (score 1):

Селекторы, это часть ОбжС и могут использоваться только с методами, которые существуют в Obj-C runtime. Нельзя вызвать селектором метод swift'а.

Если ваш класс наследован от NSObject, то все его публичные методы видны в обжС автоматически. Поскольку ваш класс не наследован от NSObject, вам надо использовать аттрибут @objc, чтобы обозначить, что вы хотите, чтобы этот метод был доступен для вызова используя selector.

`#selector()` это новый синтаксис доступный в Swift 2.2. Он позвоняет компилятору проверить, что селектор, который вы хотите вызвать существует. Старый синтаксис будет удален в Swift 3.0

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вот в чем проблема: когда я вызываю из класса presenter, который наследуется от NSObject, по селектору, метод viewController'a (UIViewController наследуется где-то вверху по иерархии от NSObject), ссылка на viewController содержится внутри presenter-класса, то теперь получаю ошибку  1) unrecognized selector sent to instance, а также Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MVPtest.ContactListPresenter updateData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd2f8d00660' [ссылка] (https://github.com/dotprox/iOS_MVP)

Comment: @DotProx там .proj файла нет

Comment: cannot be opened because it is missing its project.pbxproj file.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rktondkiiwphu10/AAAflFpGNo1xxzB9bDlOJSoga?dl=0 я не понимаю почему, git ругается на xproj